# Using CSS to give a black icon another color

Tags: css, masking

I saw some apps where even though a black icon was included, some how the app used CSS to convert the icon into a different colour.  I can't seem to repeat this process

Here's my back.css file:

```
.dashboard-buttons a {
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    margin: 0px 5px; 
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background:white; 
    text-decoration:none;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0, 0.25);
}
.dashboard-buttons a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.dashboard-buttons span, 
.dashboard-buttons img {
    display:inline; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    font-weight:bold;
}

.dashboard-buttons .sessions img { 
    background-color:#C60; 
}
.dashboard-buttons .sessions img {
    -webkit-mask-image:url(mobile/images/calendar2.png)
}
```

And the html code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="back.css" />
         <title>West</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dashboard-buttons">
            <a href="sessions.php" class="sessions">
                <img src="mobile/images/calendar2.png">
                <span>Sessions</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working in my chrome browser.  Am i missing something?

**Additional notes**  I only need to support modern webkit browsers.  Don't need to worry about IE or anything else.

I posted my code here http://jsfiddle.net/ZnbF3/ .  First time using jsfiddle, hopefully it's working? If not, just copy the html file and css file i already posted above.  I have the calendar2.png attached to this question.

[image]

Comment: did you looked up for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-image, and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_mask#Image_masks

Comment: You should have quotes around 'icon.png' in the css.

Comment: Hey guys, I added my real code to this question.  Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Yes, you need to put quoted strings in your `url` in the css.

Comment: ok, quotes added.  Still it only shows the black icon, not the orange color which i'm expecting

Comment: without back.css it's hard to analyze. Can you put a minimal example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Just mentioend that the css code i posted is the entire back.css file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the `src` attribute is being used to show up the black version on top of the orange version. You will be able to get the desired result only with CSS, this way:

```
.dashboard-buttons .sessions .img { width: 60px; height: 60px; background-color: #C60; }
.dashboard-buttons .sessions .img { -webkit-mask-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZvK4.png'); }
```

Here is the changed HTML snippet:

```
<div class="dashboard-buttons">
   <a href="sessions.php" class="sessions">
       <div class="img"></div>
       <span>Sessions</span>
   </a>
</div>​
```

And here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WHWnp/) of it.

Comment: perfect! Thank u.

Answer (score 3):

Try use background image for your image, then use another div inside the first one to apply the alpha

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #image{background-image:url(/img/2012-05-24_1834.png);width:400px;height:400px;}
        #image #image_mask{background-color:red;width:400px;height:400px;opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */}
    </style>

</head>


<body>

        <div id="image">
                <div id="image_mask"></div>
       </div>
</body>
```

sry for not using your code, i started to work in your awnser before you posted it

Comment: Good idea on that opacity